# Using XPath how do I select a node() at a specific position that is also text()?

Tags: xpath

I want to select the previous node only if it is a text node (and contains only whitespace). I have an XPath like so: `path/preceding-sibling::node()[1][normalize-space()='']`. This works great but matches both text and element nodes (if the nodes contain only whitespace). Using `path/preceding-sibling::text()[1][normalize-space()='']` will select the first preceding node that is a text node which is definitely not what I want if there are any elements in between.

How can I combine the two tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `self::text()` to test if current `node` is a text node, like so :

```
path/preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text() and normalize-space()='']
```

Comment: You are brilliant and very quick! Thank you very much for this, it works perfectly! I should have asked three hours ago and saved myself a lot of head scratching!